# How to get the build as a Release one?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an app in order to get the `Release` version I changed this value

> Build Settings -> Build options -> Build libraries for distribution = YES

but anyway after I made a build and open the `Product` folder I see that it is still in the debug

[image]

How to get the build in the release?

Comment: Archive instead? Just do no upload it, and in Organizer, you should be able to find the .archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> Xcode > Target > Edit Scheme > Run > Info > Build Configuration > Release

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot? I couldn't find `Edit Scheme` in `Target`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Where you select your device, you may see something like `MyApp (iOS) > iPhone 12 (15.0)` - click on the left box, and at the bottom you will see `Edit Scheme...`.

Comment: It is at the top on the main screen. To the right  of the "play" button. It is a drop down of your targets, third from the bottom

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko or just at top panel, `Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme ...`